# How to watch the actual image of a texture on a breakpoint while debugging three.js?

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, visual-studio-code, texture2d, vscode-debugger

I'm using VScode for three.js, with the "Debugger for Chrome" extension. Currently I'm trying to debug some code that should be working, but it doesn't, and it would be far easier if I could examine the actual image of a texture on a given breakpoint (most useful in case of a texture created on the fly along with its content, to check/verify the state of the content). Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What happens when you double click on your texture in your file system, do you see the image?

Comment: @pailhead I meant a texture created in realtime in memory along with its content in order to verify the state of the processed /drawn etc content, not a loaded image file (although a texture loaded with an image file could also be checked). Aside all the texture-structure information we get in the debugger **about** the data, I'd like to double-click the "image" part of the data and **preview** the current contents of a texture on a breakpoint -which is perfectly feasible but perhaps not implemented in VScode (question updated).